# Conditional statement inside a match case

Tags: python, match, case, python-3.10

Is it possible to have a conditional statement as a case for a match statement in Python?

Working something like this:

```
test = 'Aston Martin'
makes = ['Aston Martin', 'Bentley']

match test:
    case if test in makes:
        print(True)
    case _:
        print(False)
```

I know that match/case is not looking for something with boolean value True, but it seems like this would be useful to have for scaling things.

I tried to do it as a function so you can return the exact match:

```
test = 'Aston Martin'
makes = ['Aston Martin', 'Bentley']

def return_bool(item, lists):
    if item in lists:
        return item
    else:
        return 'notmatching'

match test:
    case return_bool(test, makes):
        print(True)
    case _:
        print(False)
```

This also didn't work. I think that it is expecting a format output, like `str(x)`.

Comment: Match cases do pattern matching, not expression evaluation. What you want is just an ordinary `if`

Comment: I think you are trying to use structural pattern matching for something that looks more like a case for if, elif, else.

Comment: Rather than making guesses based on how similar statements work in other language, you should read the [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/) that actually *describes* how it works.

Comment: `return_bool(test, makes)` is a *class pattern*, which would try to match `test` against an instance of a class named `return_bool`. It is not a function call that produces a Boolean value to match against.

Answer (score 6):

As the comments point out, the code you provided does seem like a better fit for `if/elif`, *however* it can be accomplished because `match` supports so-called "guard clauses".

```py
test = 'Aston Martin'
makes = ['Aston Martin', 'Bentley']

match test:
    case test if test in makes:
        print(True)
    case _:
        print(False)
```

This works even in cases where `makes` is not a fixed sequence. If `makes` is really just a stand-in for a fixed sequence, then you could also use

```py
test = 'Aston Martin'

match test:
    case 'Aston Martin' | 'Bentley':
        print(True)
    case _:
        print(False)
```

Note that you *cannot* do this

```py
test = 'Aston Martin'
makes = ['Aston Martin', 'Bentley']

match test:
    case makes:
        print(True)
    case _:
        print(False)
```

as this will simply always match the first case, overwriting `makes` with `test`.

Comment: The second one does not test if `test` is an element of the given list. It tries to check if `test` *is* a list containing those two elements.

Comment: You *can*, however, use `case "Aston Martin" | "Bentley":` to check against a hard-coded set of patterns.

Comment: I knew that ```case "blah" | "bla":``` was possible, I only set the list that short to use as an example. I started thinking about this because that's what I originally had but realised I was matching the same case for loads of different options, leading me to have loads of ```|``` in one case. This made me think there must be a better way.

Comment: I guess just using if, elif is the way to go. It just felt like something that there was a likely answer to. I'll go read the documentation to see what is possible.

Answer (score -3):

Use instead: `if elif`
Read to learn about match: [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/)